# Default random value in Laravel models

Tags: php, laravel, random

I am trying to set up a random default value for a Laravel model so that when a user registers a random value is saved to the database for each user.

I've looked at similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747500/how-to-set-a-default-attribute-value-for-a-laravel-eloquent-model/20621344?noredirect=1#comment54882110_20621344) on StackOverflow which explains how to setup a default value using the $attributes variable but it doesn't explain the random bit.

Comment: for random value use this function str_random();

Comment: My problem isn't regarding generating a random value but rather how one can be binded to a Laravel model by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the `save` method of your model:

```
public function save(array $options = array())
{
    if(empty($this->id)) {
        $this->someField = rand();
    }
    return parent::save($options);
}
```

Comment: Got the following error when I tried the code: ErrorException in User.php line 16:
Declaration of App\User::save() should be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::save(array $options = Array)

Answer (score 1):

For bind a field default when save model follow this

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::creating(function($post)
    {
            $post->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not providing enough info, so I'm giving you a solution: you can use a [MUTATOR](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators) in your User Model:

```
class User extends Model {
    public function setRandomStringAttribute($number)
    {
       $this->attributes['random_string'] = str_random($number);
    }
}
```

Where "random_string" is the column in your user table that holds the value. In this way each time you set the "random_string" property of a Model it's automatically set as defined. You simply use it like this:

```
$user = new User;
$user->random_string = 20;
$user->save();
```