# How to write a text into one database column for every new user during registration in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 Auth feature and registration works fine.
Now I need to write a string in a special column in users table during registration. It's not a value from an HTML form input. It's a static text describing a user role (contributor). All users registering should receive a "contributor" value in user_role column.
I tried to achieve this by adding this line to AuthController.php:

```
'user_role' => 'contributor',
```

The whole function adding values to database looks like this:

```
/**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'user_role' => 'contributor',
        ]);
    }
```

When I try to register a new account, everything except `'user_role' => 'contributor',` gets added.

What's the proper way to write "contributor" value for every new user into the user_role column?
Is it not working because that function only has the $data array set?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a default attribute value for a Laravel / Eloquent model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747500/how-to-set-a-default-attribute-value-for-a-laravel-eloquent-model)

Comment: This issue is completely different from the one you provided. It's from another part of Laravel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you add `user_role` to `$fillable` array on User model ?

If not you need to add it

Example

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'user_role'];
```